# In a Big Rip scenario, would color confinement cause a singularity to form?

Tags: particle-physics, quarks, confinement, gluons

The energy in a gluon tube between quarks increases approximately linearly with the distance between them, and when that energy is sufficient to spawn a quark-antiquark pair out of the vacuum, it does so. Two separated hadrons are the by-products of the stretching.

In a Big Rip end-of-the-universe scenario, the rate at which spacetime expands will increase exponentially, such that galaxies will be pulled apart so far and quickly that light will never be able to reach one from the other. Then the same will happen to individual star systems within each galaxy, then to planets within star systems, and finally to individual particles - separated so far apart that nothing will interact with anything else ever again.

My question is, when the expansion of the universe is such that it pulls individual particles apart, what will happen to confined quarks? If expanding spacetime causes individual quarks to drift apart, then will they be pulled apart such a distance that their gluon tubes will split and spawn more hadrons?

If the cosmological event horizon shrinks smaller than the radius of a hadron, then individual quarks will not even physically be able to influence each other, and color confinement will fail in general (which I suppose would imply the answer is 'No'). However, for a (very brief) period of time before that moment, quarks *would* be pulled away from each other by expanding spacetime, and so is there also enough time for a scenario like this to take place?

One possibility, if this is the case: would hadrons continue to spawn and multiply with the expansion of spacetime and accumulate to such an amount that the total new mass is sufficient to form a singularity - possibly another 'big bang'?

Another possibility: the expansion of spacetime is *so* fast and strong, that even though hadrons split and spawn ('reproducing' exponentially), the expansion swiftly carries the new hadrons far away from each other, and mass does not accumulate in any region. Then, the cosmological event horizon reaches the radius of a hadron, and color confinement fails across the universe.

Are any of these scenarios plausible? Would something else happen in a scenario like this, or can we even guess what will happen (can physics even be extrapolated into such an extreme universe and still make sensible predictions)?